# Microsoft SMS Sender

Tags: c#-2.0

how does it works?
I am developing an identical application where i search for available GSM Modem 
and then send messages using it.

but whenever i try send an sms i get write time out exception?
what can be the cause for this exception?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Microsoft SMS sender once, using the not-command line way (visual interface). Make sure that you will send it with log enabled.

The exception occurs because SMS sender can't select the GSM device automatically. After you used it to send for visual interface with enabled log, it will work correctly.